# Compile-time register checks for Thumb-2 code

Tags: assembly, arm, compiler-warnings, thumb

In Thumb-2 code, it is not possible to use registers 8-15 in most instructions, while this is possible in ARM code. Hence, the following assembly gives a runtime Illegal Instruction error:

```
        .syntax unified
        .fpu    vfp
        .thumb
        .text
        .globl  main
main:
        str r12,[sp,#-4]    @ r12 is too high, source register is 3 bits wide
```

However, I do not get a warning at compile time, even though I use `-Wall`:

```
pi@rasppi:~/ctests$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -Wall -o high.o high.s 
ARM GAS  high.s                         page 1


   1                                    .syntax unified
   2                                    .fpu    vfp
   3                                    .thumb
   4                                    .text
   5                                    .globl  main
   6                            main:
   7 0000 4DF804CC                      str r12,[sp,#-4]
pi@rasppi:~/ctests$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wall -o high high.o 
pi@rasppi:~/ctests$ ./high 
Illegal instruction
pi@rasppi:~/ctests$ file high
high: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=c9d90a7d6386bf97a18f9da87a7b2ce422402659, not stripped
```

Is there any tool that can be used to check for illegal instructions at compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that you have Thumb code at the symbol `main`, but haven't annotated that as a Thumb symbol. Thus the linker doesn't set the lsb of the symbol address, so at runtime the call gets there in ARM state and subsequently chokes on a Thumb encoding. To solve that, you need to add the [`.thumb_func` annotation](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html#ARM-Directives):

```
...
.globl main
.thumb_func
main:
...
```

With that in place, it's highly likely to still crash with either an undefined instruction or a segfault when you run off the end of that code into whatever code/data/unmapped page follows. You need to actually return from `main`.

Your initial assumption is incorrect, because if it *were* a problem with register usage as you suspect, it wouldn't even assemble. The "tool that can be used to check for illegal instructions at compile time" *is* the assembler.

Comment: Thanks! It works when I add `bx lr` at the end of `main`, to return.

Answer (score 3):

The `R0-R7` restriction only applies to 16-bit Thumb, not 32-bit Thumb-2 (see [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0100a/armasm_cihgjhed.htm)). The 32-bit `STR.W` has 4 bits for the register (encodings [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads159/doc/709030/Thumb-2SupplementReferenceManual.pdf)). In fact, GCC is indeed generating a `STR.W` instruction (`4DF804CC`).

The illegal instruction is likely caused by your target not supporting Thumb-2. You should properly define your target (`-mthumb`, `-march`, `-mcpu`, `-mfpu`, ...) so that the assembler knows what can and can't be used.

Now that you've added that you're on a Raspberry Pi 3, Model B, I'd try those flags: `-march=armv8-a+crc -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard` (from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=144115)). Since it's 64-bit ARM, the issue is not that it doesn't support Thumb-2, but that you can't switch AArch64 <-> AArch32 inside your program.

Comment: I see, thanks. How do I find the right settings for `-march` and `-mcpu`? [Here](http://termbin.com/r6mn) is my `/proc/cpuinfo`; this is a Raspberry Pi 3, model B.

Comment: @CamilStaps I think the problem in this case might be that the program you generated is a 64 bit ARM program. Your assembler might let you switch to thumb mode inside such a program, but the resulting code won't work.

Comment: @CamilStaps Added the flags. I had totally missed the `pi@rasppi` prompt...

Comment: @CamilStaps I mean, there is no way that core doesn't support thumb2. OP likely just needs to instruct his compiler to generate a 32 bit program; not sure though, how.

Comment: @FUZxxl Well, one could compile for a 32-bit ARM CPU so that the compiler generates AArch32 code and links it to a 32-bit executable, the OS will do the rest. Not sure how that ties in with FPU and extensions, though.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo I think you just need to pass a flag similar to `-m32` on x86 to make the compiler compile a 32 bit binary. I don't think setting a 32 bit CPU will help, I think you just get the message “cpu does not support aarch64.”

Comment: AArch64 is almost certainly irrelevant - a 32-bit (i.e. `arm-*`) toolchain, which is being used here, is incapable of generating or linking 64-bit code. Plus the standard Raspberry Pi 3 userspace is entirely 32-bit anyway.

Comment: @Notlikethat Wait, what? The Raspberry Pi 3 is a 64 bit CPU. Why the hell do they not ship a 64 bit toolchain with it?

Comment: @FUZxxl Because they have a single userspace image for all 3 generations of boards, and AFAIK the 3 is still running basically the same 32-bit kernel as the 2 - if you want to run 64-bit software you've got install your own AArch64 kernel and userspace.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the late reply. I now assemble with those flags (without `-mtune`, which is unrecognized) and link with those flags (with `-mtune`), but it still doesn't work. I'm getting an illegal instruction at `0x10932 vcgt.s8 q8, <illegal reg q6.5>, #0`, while I cannot find that instruction using `objdump`. Any idea what could be going wrong?